# Error trying to login in with Firebase with Facebook Sign In Credential

Tags: android, facebook, flutter

## Objective

Integrate Facebook Login to my Flutter app. Manage to integrate it with the existing Firebase 
configuration (Google Sign In Auth and Firestore Database).

## Step by Step to reproduce my error:

1) I have created a new app on Facebook Developers and follow up the step by step to configure my app to call the Facebook Login (add what is needed to strings.xml and to AndroidManifest)

2) Go to Firebase Console, activate the Facebook Sign In option and add App Id and App secret with the same info added to the app.

3) Return to Facebook Developer and edit Facebook Login > Configuration to add the

> https://myappname.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

into the OAuth valid redirects.

3) Add the package flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1 to flutter and update packages
4) Implement the following code to be call on a material button onPress:

```
 final _facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
 Future<FirebaseUser> facebookSignIn() async {
    loading.add(true);
    final result = await _facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);

    if(result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
      final AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
          accessToken: result.accessToken.token
      );

      final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

      updateUserData(user);
      print("sign in " + user.displayName);

      return user;
    }

    loading.add("false");
    return null;
  }
```

6) Receive this error:

> E/flutter (22866): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
>   Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL, The
>   supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Unsuccessful
>   debug_token response from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth
>   access token
>   signature.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"MY_FB_TRACE_ID"}}
>   ], null)

This error, as I searched about is something wrong with the OAuth configuration on step 3, but I returned and check multiple times.

Does anyone knows if there is another thing I must check to make this work?

Comment: Perhaps you went over a quota? Did you end up resolving this?

Comment: @icsvnc, what did you do to resolve it? Will appreciate your help.

Comment: @bangbang I haven't solved this issue, I have ended configuring Google Sign In and left without Facebook Sign In.